# How can I find out what calls the push-mark function in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Sometimes while editing a file in haskell-mode I get an unexpected message `Mark set` when saving a file. By tracing the function `push-mark`, I notice that it seems to be called with arguments `nil nil t`, which I don't quite understand (location is the first argument). I don't know where it is called from or why.

Is there a way to find out what calls it, and maybe stop execution and examine the call stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `M-: (debug-on-entry 'push-mark)`. This should display the call stack when `push-mark` is called. You may later cancel it with `M-: (cancel-debug-on-entry 'push-mark)`.